# Showing Error in using case in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Please Help finding the error...

```
DECLARE @TDT DATETIME; SET @TDT ='20-AUG-2013 05:00:000 PM';
DECLARE @SSN INT; SET @SSN = 1;
set @SSN =case LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @TDT, 100), 2)) when 'PM' then 1
```

error shows...

```
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

Comment: and what must you END a case expression with?

Comment: Thanks ... @GregHewgill for givind me clue..

Comment: `DECLARE` can handle assignment for you since _SS 2008_ and `DATETIME` is already time aware so you can simplify/speed-up things a bit with:
`DECLARE @TDT DATETIME = '20-AUG-2013 11:59:000 AM';`
`DECLARE @SSN BIT = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @TDT) >= 12 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add end to the statement

```
case LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @TDT, 100), 2)) when 'PM' then 1 END
```